# Performance Comparision visual decoration on iPhone via various methods

Tags: ios, performance

Suppose we need to decorate a UIButton, UIView, etc. in iOS we use the following methods,

1. use the CALayer properties like borderWidth, CATransform, CAGradientLayer, etc.
2. use the drawRect: method of UIView and perform our decoration drawing via CG.
3. use just an already prepared image to be drawn on the UIView's or its layer's background.

Now, my question is out of the above 3 which one takes less processing time and give more speed (performance boost) ?

As I have noticed that on views which are constantly getting updates (visually) like a tableview; even if the layer.shouldRasterise = YES is applied, the performance is still very poor. And if the cornerRadius is active, then the performance becomes more poor.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on situation, if you don't care about memory consumption - images should work best, on the other hand if you want to minimize memory footprint - CALayer+drawing does the job for me.

As of cornerRadius and other similar properties - you can easily get the same job done by drawing, that would be more efficient.

Also check latest WWDC sessions, there was one (I don't remember the name) about UIKit/CoreGraphics performance tuning.